# Rails model default value being ignored when new record created?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-6, rails-migrations, rails-models

I have a Message model like so

```
class CreateMessages < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :messages do |t|
      t.text :body
      t.references :conversation, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.references :user, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.boolean :seen, default: false
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

I expected `default: false` to set the value of 'seen' to `false` whenever a new message is created

But when I try

```
Message.create(conversation_id: 1, body: "something new!", user_id: 1)
```

Then `seen: nil`. Whereas I was expecting to see `seen: false`

Have I done something wrong / how can I get the desired behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reload your console by running the bellow command in your rails console or you can close and reopen your console once. I think, it'll solve your issue. Other than codes are looking good to me.

```
reload!
```